# how to get the values of the radio button which has been checked , jquery

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

can we get the values of the radio buttons , only those which has been checked , 
cause i have to implement a form in which there are many radio buttons , so how can i get all the values which has been checked 
what i have to do is

i have 13 subjects like : physics , math , biology .....
and the students can choose any number of subjects , and each subject will have two radio buttons one is A and the another is As ,

so how can i get the values of the radio buttons which has been checked?
using jquery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would loop through all the radio elements in the document that have been checked:

```
$('input:radio:checked').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    // do something with radio or value
});
```

If you wanted to get the checked value of a particular radio group, you would do:

```
var value = $('input:radio[name=myradios]:checked').val();
```

So if your HTML was like this:

```
<input type='radio' name='myradios' value='1'>
<input type='radio' name='myradios' value='2' checked='checked'>
<input type='radio' name='myradios' value='3'>
```

`value` would be 2

Comment: what if the radio buttons have different name like : physics will have two radio buttons with same name so that they can choose betn A and As physics like wise two radio buttons for biology, and like wise for other 11 subjects , how can i get the values of the checked radio buttons only?

Comment: The first example would get the values of all the checked ones.