# How to check radio button is checked using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have two radio buttons in one group, I want to check the radio button is checked or not using JQuery, How ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the values of the radio button which has been checked , jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083644/how-to-get-the-values-of-the-radio-button-which-has-been-checked-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check of specific radio button is checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195125/check-of-specific-radio-button-is-checked)

Comment: Mentioned questions in the above comments are asking how to get the checked value and check specific value has choosed, not for validate whether it's checked or not. So, it's different.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Given a group of radio buttons:

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioGroup" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioGroup" value="2">
```

You can test whether a specific one is checked using jQuery as follows:

```
if ($("#radio1").prop("checked")) {
   // do something
}

// OR
if ($("#radio1").is(":checked")) {
   // do something
}

// OR if you don't have ids set you can go by group name and value
// (basically you need a selector that lets you specify the particular input)
if ($("input[name='radioGroup'][value='1']").prop("checked"))
```

You can get the value of the currently checked one in the group as follows:

```
$("input[name='radioGroup']:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 10):

The following code checks if your radio button having name like 'yourRadioName'  is checked or not:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($("input:radio[name='yourRadioName']").is(":checked")) {
      //its checked
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is best practice

```
$("input[name='radioGroup']:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery 3.3.1

```
if (typeof $("input[name='yourRadioName']:checked").val() === "undefined") {
    alert('is not selected');
}else{
    alert('is selected');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are,

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio_1" class="radioButtons" name="radioButton" value="1">
<input type="radio" id="radio_2" class="radioButtons" name="radioButton" value="2">
```

to check on click,

```
$('.radioButtons').click(function(){
    if($("#radio_1")[0].checked){
       //logic here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var rdValue = $("input[name='radioGroup']:checked").val();
if(rdValue == '' || typeof rdValue === "undefined") {   
    console.log("not checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out, too:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  if($("input:radio[name='yourRadioGroupName'][value='yourvalue']").is(":checked")) { 
      //its checked 
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var count =0;

$('input[name="radioGroup"]').each(function(){
  if (this.checked)
    {
      count++;
    }
});
```

If any of radio button checked than you will get 1

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can check the property.

```
if( $("input[name='radioButtonName']").prop('checked') ){
    //implement your logic
  }else{
    //do something else as radio not checked   
  }
```