# How to compare the value of selected value in radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="ckbLstPartner" runat="server" 
                                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="cssRdlstMoheSacm">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Good Day for everybody,  I don't know why it's not taking an action when I compare the val() with '1' to get the tr displayed, please advice.

```
$('#<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>').change(function () {
     if ($('#<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>').find('option:checked').val() == '1') {

            $('#trSetPartnerNamesAvailability').show();
            $('#trSetPartnerInfoAvailability').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#trSetPartnerNamesAvailability').hide();
            $('#trSetPartnerInfoAvailability').hide();
            $('#<%= txtPartnersName.ClientID %>').val('');
            $('#<%= txtReqScoreCourseAccept.ClientID %>').val('');
            $('#<%= txtCourseAcceptNote.ClientID %>').val('');
```

Comment: I don't know where is the mistake ?

Comment: did you put this: $('#<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>').change(function ().... 
in $(document).ready(function() {  ... ????

Comment: check with this link 
http://www.dotnetprogram.com/articles/call-javascript-function-for-radiobuttonlist-onchange-event-in-jquery

Comment: no, I didn't use .ready()

Comment: the val() of both radiobuttons are (((Undefined))) after display it by alert(). ?? Why ?

Comment: what logic you are followed.if checked you show tr.else you hide tr.what abt txtboxes whether to show in the same manner?i mean to show and hide the text boxes based on radio button lists

Comment: because if 'No' checked, I want to clear the current values of txtboxes to prevent them storing in DB.

Comment: so need to show txtboxes in both cases.but txtbox becomes null when no selected.right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your IF condition like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>').change(function () {
            if ($("input[name='<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>'][value='1']").prop("checked")) {

                $('#<%=trSetPartnerNamesAvailability.ClientID%>').show();
                $('#<%=trSetPartnerInfoAvailability.ClientID%>').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#<%=trSetPartnerNamesAvailability.ClientID%>').hide();
                $('#<%=trSetPartnerInfoAvailability.ClientID%>').hide();
                $('#<%= txtPartnersName.ClientID %>').val('');
                $('#<%= txtReqScoreCourseAccept.ClientID %>').val('');
                $('#<%= txtCourseAcceptNote.ClientID %>').val('');
            }
        });
    });
```

**Note:**

1)In asp.net if you give id,Name is automatically same as id.So beware of "NAME" attribute.Based on name i write the logic.

2)More about jquery .Refer http://try.jquery.com/ They give jquery in simple manner and also give importance of ready function.

3)More about radio button list changed event logic.Refer [How to check radio button is checked using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725172/how-to-check-radio-button-is-checked-using-jquery)

**Updated Answer(If Anybody Use Master Page For The Above Logic):**
when we use Master Page.We have two content place holders.one for head sectoin.Another for Body section.So i place my javascript file in content placeholder1.See below code.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                if ($("input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ckbLstPartner'][value='1']").prop("checked")) {

                    $('#<%=trSetPartnerNamesAvailability.ClientID%>').show();
                    $('#<%=trSetPartnerInfoAvailability.ClientID%>').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#<%=trSetPartnerNamesAvailability.ClientID%>').hide();
                    $('#<%=trSetPartnerInfoAvailability.ClientID%>').hide();
                    $('#<%= txtPartnersName.ClientID %>').val('');
                    $('#<%= txtReqScoreCourseAccept.ClientID %>').val('');
                    $('#<%= txtCourseAcceptNote.ClientID %>').val('');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .cssRdlstMoheSacm
        {}
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

The above two codes are 99% same with small modification i.e;

**Webform Without using Master Page:**

```
if ($("input[name='ckbLstPartner'][value='1']").prop("checked")) {}
```

**WebForm Using Master Page:**

```
if ($("input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ckbLstPartner'][value='1']").prop("checked")) {}
```

Comment: I'm becoming crazy because of that, Why it gave Undefined value ??

Comment: The problem is here?? when I check the source of page >> id="ctl00_BodyContentPlaceholder_ckbPartner and the other propertiess is coming with prefix:  ct100_BodyContentPlaceholder ?

Comment: im here.i cant see any id like ctl00_BodyContentPlaceholder_ckbPartner in your code?will you post entire aspx page.i can check it.

Comment: No My friend, The prefix is shown once I run the app on localhost or server. When I check the source of the page from the browser, The complete name and Id will be shown. and I think we should either change the ClientIDMode property or take the complete name from the page sourse >> Confirm plz which logic is better.    and Thanks for follow up.

Comment: alert($("input:radio[name='ctl00$BodyContentPlaceholder$ckbLstPartner']:checked").val());

Comment: Great Answer, I did the required modification yesterday. But your explanation was really very important. Thanks mr AJay

Comment: Welcome,Happy programming