# jQuery - Tried to check if radiobutton is checked, but it says it is even when it isn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I've been looking for half an hour now to try and get a function to work that un-checks my radiobuttons if clicked again. My function is currently looking like this (with alert's to see what the heck is going on):

```js
function radUncheck(id)
{
    alert(id + " " + $("#" + id).prop('checked'));
    if ($("#" + id).prop('checked'))
    {
        alert($("#" + id).prop('checked'));
        $("#" + id).prop('checked', false);
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="semesterlage-ss-a" name="semesterlage" value="SS" onclick="radUncheck(\'semesterlage-ss-a\')"/>
      <label for="semesterlage-ss-a">SS</label>
<input type="radio" id="semesterlage-ws-a" name="semesterlage" value="WS" onclick="radUncheck(\'semesterlage-ss-a\')"/>
      <label for="semesterlage-ws-a">WS</label>
```

However whenever I try it it says that #semesterlage-ss-a would be true (checked) no matter if it is or not, and #semesterlage-ws-a would be false (unchecked) no matter if it is or not.

Comment: Do you really want a radio button or a checkbox?

Comment: @ChrisP I cannot use checkboxes since you are only allowed to choose one option, rather than several as it is possible to do with checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a data attribute to the radio. This indicates the state of the radio (The problem is the radio is on click allways checked).

```js
function radUncheck(elm) {

  if ($(elm).data('checked')) {     // If the radio is already checked
    $(elm).prop('checked', false);  // Uncheck this radio
    $(elm).data('checked', '');     // Remove data attribute

  } else {
  var name = $(elm).attr('name');   // Get the name of this radio
    $('input[name="' + name + '"]').data('checked', ''); // remove all data attributes from this radio name group
    $(elm).data('checked', true);   // Set new data attribute to this radio to indicate that it is selected
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="semesterlage-ss-a" name="semesterlage" value="SS" onclick="radUncheck(this)"/>
      <label for="semesterlage-ss-a">SS</label>
<input type="radio" id="semesterlage-ws-a" name="semesterlage" value="WS" onclick="radUncheck(this)"/>
      <label for="semesterlage-ws-a">WS</label>
```

Comment: The \' is necessary since in my actual code the whole thing is surrounded by ' '. It wouldn't really fix the problem either way, though. If you run your snippet you see that whenever you click SS it gives you the value "true" and whenever you click WS it gives you the value "false". That's my problem...

Comment: Thats normal since you allways select the SS radio button. That is false if the WS radio is selected

Comment: Updated my answer. When WS is selected, it returns true, if not, it returns false

Comment: The console.log seems correct now, however the radio buttons are still not unselectable...

Comment: I've updated my answer. This should serve your needs

Comment: glad I could help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data attribut to do that.

See example:

```js
function radUncheck(el) {
  if ($(el).data('checked')) {
    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false).data('checked', '');
  } else {
    $('input[type="radio"]').data('checked', '');
    $(el).data('checked', true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="semesterlage-ss-a" data-checked="" name="semesterlage" value="SS" onclick="radUncheck(this)" />
<label for="semesterlage-ss-a">SS</label>
<input type="radio" id="semesterlage-ws-a" data-checked="" name="semesterlage" value="WS" onclick="radUncheck(this)" />
<label for="semesterlage-ws-a">WS</label>
```

Note : Use `console.log` instead `alert` to debug your code.

Comment: The console.log still gives always true for SS and always false for WS. The SS seems uncheckable now, though I do not understand how, but the WS still is not.

Comment: This is because you pass always the SS id on the two case.

Comment: You pass the same id by parameter : `semesterlage-ss-a`

Comment: i just found it, and i actually do! Thank you for catching that

Answer (score 0):

try this one or follow this link may by helpful for you.
[How to check radio button is checked using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725172/how-to-check-radio-button-is-checked-using-jquery)

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
     function radUncheck(id)
        {
          var radioValue = $("input[name='semesterlage']:checked").val();
          if ($("#radio1").prop("checked")) {
            // do something
          }
          // OR
          if ($("#radio1").is(":checked")) {
            // do something
          }
          // OR if you don't have ids set you can go by group name and value
          // (basically you need a selector that lets you specify the particular input)
          if ($("input[name='radioGroup'][value='1']").prop("checked"))
         }
         <!-- language: lang-html -->
         <input type="radio" id="semesterlage-ss-a" name="semesterlage" value="SS" onclick="radUncheck(\'semesterlage-ss-a\')"/>
                    <label for="semesterlage-ss-a">SS</label>
        <input type="radio" id="semesterlage-ws-b" name="semesterlage" value="WS" onclick="radUncheck(\'semesterlage-ss-b\')"/>
                    <label for="semesterlage-ws-b">WS</label>
```

Comment: This is basically what I did... the issue remains unfortunately.